# For loop in NDK makefile to define static libraries

Tags: android, shell, makefile, android-ndk

I have a common.mk file that I include in each of my NDK `Android.mk` files that defines the static libraries I have available. For boost, I wanted to try something clever like this:

```
BOOST_COMPONENTS = \
    filesystem \
    system \
    thread \
    atomic

for c in $(BOOST_COMPONENTS) ; do \
    include $(CLEAR_VARS) ; \
    LOCAL_MODULE := boost_$$(c) ; \
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../../../../../Core/ThirdParty/boost/lib/android/libboost_$$(c)-gcc-mt-s-1_55.a ; \
    include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY) ; \
done
```

However, even though I don't see any direct errors with this when I build, I get linker errors because the boost symbols are not found. This tells me it isn't properly setting these up.

How can I make this work?